# Why is my program adding an extra day to a non leap year?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

This is my program where I find the day of the year based on a date put in. I also have to take into account for leap years. I have all that but when a year put in such as 12/31/1993 is put in, I get the day as 366 which is incorrect because it's not a leap year so the day of the year should be 365. I've tested whether it's my if statement by just giving the program the ability to only test for leap years and to close out if its a non leap year. When the same date was entered, the program closed out telling me that the problem doesn't lie in my if statement but in my case and switches. I'm not really sure as to what's happening or why its adding the extra day to the date.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int month,day,year,day_number=0;

    printf("Enter a date in the form (01/02/1996): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month,&day,&year);


    if(((year%4 == 0) && (year%100 !=0)) || (year%400==0)){
        goto two;
    }
    else{
        month=month;
        goto one;
    }

    one:
        switch(month)
        {
            case 1:day_number=day;
                break;
            case 2:day_number=31+day; //January+Febuary
                break;
            case 3:day_number=59+day; //January+Febuary+March
                break;
            case 4:day_number=90+day; //January+Febuary+March+April
                break;
            case 5:day_number=120+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May
                break;
            case 6:day_number=151+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June
                break;
            case 7:day_number=181+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July
                break;
            case 8:day_number=212+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August
                break;
            case 9:day_number=243+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September
                break;
            case 10:day_number=273+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September+October
                break;
            case 11:day_number=304+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September+October+November
                break;
            case 12:day_number=334+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September+October+November+December
                break;
        }
    two:
        switch(month)
        {
            case 1:day_number=day;
                break;
            case 2:day_number=31+day; //January+Febuary
                break;
            case 3:day_number=60+day; //January+Febuary+March
                break;
            case 4:day_number=91+day; //January+Febuary+March+April
                break;
            case 5:day_number=121+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May
                break;
            case 6:day_number=151+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June
                break;
            case 7:day_number=182+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July
                break;
            case 8:day_number=213+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August
                break;
            case 9:day_number=243+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September
                break;
            case 10:day_number=274+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September+October
                break;
            case 11:day_number=304+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September+October+November
                break;
            case 12:day_number=335+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September+October+November+December
                break;
        }
    printf("day %d\n", day_number);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the expression `month=month` supposed to do? And `goto`?

Comment: Why not use an array instead of switch

Comment: I'm fully aware of the month=month is not nessecary I just copied and pasted right after I tested so that was just one of my ways of testing and I guess I forgot to remove it before posting to here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a return after the label `one:`. Because after execution of `one:` two is also getting executed.

Moreover,

1. Always try to avoid the use of `goto` statements
2. `month=month` line is completely unnecessary.
3. There is a lot of code repetition.

A somewhat better approach will be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

  int month,day,year,day_number=0;

  printf("Enter a date in the form (01/02/1996): ");
  scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month,&day,&year);




  switch(month)
  {
     case 1:day_number=day;
           break;
    case 2:day_number=31+day; //January+Febuary
           break;
    case 3:day_number=59+day; //January+Febuary+March
           break;
    case 4:day_number=90+day; //January+Febuary+March+April
           break;
    case 5:day_number=120+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May
           break;
    case 6:day_number=151+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June
           break;
    case 7:day_number=181+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July
           break;
    case 8:day_number=212+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August
           break;
    case 9:day_number=243+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September
           break;
    case 10:day_number=273+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September+October
           break;
    case 11:day_number=304+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September+October+November
           break;
    case 12:day_number=334+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September+October+November+December
           break;
  }

  if(((year%4 == 0) && (year%100 !=0)) || (year%400==0))
  {
       if(month>2)
       ++day_number;
  }


  printf("day %d\n", day_number);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the break was exiting out of the case statement and becuase the if statement at the top wasn't true, there was no reason for it to go on to the second case.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the info on goto statements! I use them because our proff want's us to write our programs according to what weve gone over in lecture and so I was using goto's because in our lecture pp and notes, that's what she was using. Wasn't aware that they weren't necessary and that this could be simplified down to something like this.

Comment: @Senglish Yes, goto statements are completely unnecessary and using them is a bad c practice. You should never use them. However, If it was for learning purpose then it doesn't hurt. :-)

Comment: @Senglish The answer advises to try to avoid using `goto`s.  Beware that there are occassions when using a `goto` is more correct than the alternatives.  I develop software for very small microcontrollers, where every byte counts and a couple of `goto` statements (or similar) can make the difference between code my customer can use and well structured rubbish.  Mid-method `return`s are effectively the same as `goto` and a `switch` is just a bunch of `if ... goto` blocks.  Search for 'why is goto bad' to find lots of information on when `goto` is wrong and when it is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

After the code has gone through the label `one:`, there is nothing to stop it from executing everything under the label `two:`. So, it executes those lines also.

**Update**

`goto` statements are so last century :) Avoid them unless there is no other way.

You can reduce a lot of the redundant code by using suitable functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_non_leap_year_day()
{
   switch(month)
   {
      case 1:
         return day;

      case 2:
         return 31+day; //January+Febuary

      case 3:
         return 59+day; //January+Febuary+March

      case 4:
         return 90+day; //January+Febuary+March+April

      case 5:
         return 120+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May

      case 6:
         return 151+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June

      case 7:
         return 181+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July

      case 8:
         return 212+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August

      case 9:
         return 243+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September

      case 10:
         return 273+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September+October

      case 11:
         return 304+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September+October+November

      case 12:
         return 334+day; //January+Febuary+March+April+May+June+July+August+September+October+November+December
   }

   // Never should come here.
   // Add a return to keep the compiler happy.
   return 0;
}

int get_leap_year_day()
{
   int day_number = get_leap_year_day();
   if ( month > 2 )
   {
      day_number++;
   }
   return day_number;
}

int main(void)
{
   int month,day,year,day_number=0;

   printf("Enter a date in the form (01/02/1996): ");
   scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month,&day,&year);

   if(((year%4 == 0) && (year%100 !=0)) || (year%400==0))
   {
      day_number = get_leap_year_day(month, day);
   }
   else
   {
      day_number = get_non_leap_year_day(month, day);
   }

   printf("day %d\n", day_number);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an array to simplify code. i.e.

```
static int days_in_non_leap_year[] = 
   {-1, 0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334 }; 

if (((year%4 == 0) && (year%100 !=0)) || (year%400==0)) {
   day_number = days_in_non_leap_year[month] + 1 + days;
} else {
   day_number = days_in_non_leap_year[month] + days;
}
```

Of course you should also check the inputs as well. The -1 is because the months start at 1 - it is just a filler